# Creating monopoly and Ludo in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a monopoly board and the ludo game in Visual Basic.NET 2010.
How should I represent the board? I was thinking of picture boxes, but then they get too clumsy to handle individually. Can you create arrays of picture boxes?

Also, since I am just a novice programmer, can you tell what features of Visual Basic will be useful for this game?

Comment: Actually, I desperately want a method for board representation. Last time, when i created chess, I had used 64 picture boxes and accessing them and changing their properties turned out to be very inefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding controls in the Forms designer, you can always add them programmatically in VB (and C#). This gives you the freedom of storing them wherever you want as in a two-dimensional array. Be sure to add them to the `Form.Controls` property as well.

```
Dim board as New PictureBox(M-1, N-1) {}

myform.SuspendLayout() ' Diminishes flicker.
For i As Integer = 0 To M - 1
    For k As Integer = 0 To N - 1
        Dim pic = New PictureBox()
        'TODO: set the properties of the PictureBox here
        board(i, k) = pic
        myForm.Controls.Add(pic)
    Next k
Next i
myForm.ResumeLayout()
```

Also consider adding the `PictureBoxes` to a `TableLayoutPanel` instead of adding them directly to the form.

And, of cause, it is a good idea to create a `Board` class and to handle all the board logic in that class instead of performing the logic in the form event handlers. Other classes like `Player` or `Game` or `Score` can be helpful as well.

It would be even a better idea not to create a 2-D-array of PictureBoxes but an array of some `Square` class that could store additional information like the state of a square or a list of figures staying on the square or a reference to a special rule that applies to a square and so on. You have a great freedom in the design of a game. A smart design separating game logic from UI details is much easier to handle and can evolve more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a PictureBox, I would consider creating a UserControl that encapsulates all the UI-related logic related to a square on the board.  For instance, you may want all the squares on the board to have a particular right-click context menu, or do something in particular when double-clicked.  In Monopoly, you may want each square to have a Property Name, price, color, etc.

Comment: Okay. I haven't used a usercontrol before actually. So, I think I might go with this